# Emoji support and MariaDB 10.0.30-

Tags: database, emoji

I am using Wordpress 4.7.3 with the built in Emojii support. We have recently moved to MariaDB 10.0.30, but the original wp-config indicates define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8). I have noticed that I cannot use emojis and, for example, if I try to include an emoji as category and have enabled the debug mode, I am returned with this:

```
WordPress database error: [Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=']
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND t.name IN (':smile:') ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

How difficult is to make my Db "emoji compatible"?

Thank you,

Regards